# “Half-made bread” for dough

Tags: meaning

I’m making bread. I made dough, a mixture of water and flour. And I’ll make complete bread only if I bake the dough. In this situation, can I call the dough “half-made bread”? I was inspired to write this post by https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/512237/can-i-use-the-verb-finish-in-present-continuous-tense.

[image]

Comment: Maybe [half-done](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/half-done)?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Yes, does “half-done bread” indicate the dough?

Comment: It's not a natural expression, because the dough doesn't become bread until it is baked. Similarly, 'cake mixture' or 'cake batter' only becomes cake when baked.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you. Then, I better just to say bread is half-made, not indicating the dough?

Comment: It depends on the circumstances. You could say "I'm halfway through making (the) bread" or "I'm kneading the dough" (as in your picture).

Comment: I agree; the *process* of making the bread is half-done, or the bread is half-made, but dough is not "half-made bread", it's just dough.

Comment: Calling dough "half-made bread" is a bit like saying a pig is a "half-made sausage".

Answer (score 2):

"Half-made" bread sounds like you took it out of the oven halfway through the cooking time and it is only half baked. The process is: ingredients - dough - baking - bread. What you are describing is called dough.

Answer (score 1):

Why!?

That stuff is called **dough**, as you well know.  It's not called "half-made bread".

Would you call an egg an "unmade omelette"?  Surely not.  If there is a common word for something, you should use that word.